# svn update on commit with a phrase

Tags: svn, hook

I have some non-server-savy people work on some webpages that I want to put in svn.

To avoid me having to go onto servers and update the code I'd like to have the code be updated automatically based on the commit message. (e.g. "BUILD_TEST" or "BUILD_PROD")

Would the best way to do his to have a post-commit hook that would use svnlook to determine the message and then ssh to the appropriate server and do a svn update?